# Unable to Copy/Paste in directories Linux Mint Debain Mate

Tags: linux, debian, copy-paste, linux-mint

I am using the latest version of linux mint debian edition. However, I am unable to copy files between directories. For example : I cannot fopy a txt file from the Desktop to my Documents folder even though the folders have proper permission.

What could be the problem ? Is it a bug in the Debian Mint ?

Comment: how are you trying to copy? terminal using `cp`? desktop using some fancy file-manager? which one?

Comment: nop. I'm just trying to do Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V. It doesn't work.

Comment: where do you Ctrl-C Ctrol V? in the console? in some fancy file-manager? which one? how do you select your files?

Answer (score 0):

in konsole

```
$id
$ls -al
```

look u permition file

Answer (score -1):

you must login or user level

```
root || super user

use sudo or su in terminal
```

Comment: are you seriously suggesting that you have to be root to copy files in the ${USER}s home directory?